# Case law, statutory law, the UK and the European Union

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

I have been told that "statutory law" is a "blunt instrument" (presumably due to the cost of change?) and that the UK legal system has developed a system whereby a more flexible "case law" is used to ameliorate this problem, leading to a legal system that is well regarded.

Does the law-making system of the European Union have a similar design, or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Without firther specifying what you're looking for, it sounds like you're comparing apples and oranges. The EU court has in fact called the EU a "new legal order."

Comment: Common law (what you're referring to as "case law") originated _before_ statute law. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_law#Common_law).

Comment: Related https://law.stackexchange.com/q/22149/344